# "Could not find JSS app configuration" error during JSS import

Tags: jss

I'm attempting to import one of the JSS [sample applications](https://github.com/Sitecore/jss) and I'm getting the following error after running the `npm run package` command:

```
Fatal error occurred while running import process.
Exception: Sitecore.Install.Utils.InstallationException
Message: Could not find JSS app configuration for 'JssAdvancedApp'. Ensure you have included or previously installed a configuration patch for the app.
Source: Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.UpdatePackage.PostInstallImportApp.DoRun(ILog logger, NameValueCollection metadata)
    at Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.AppServices.UpdatePackage.PostInstallImportApp.Run(ILog logger, NameValueCollection metadata)
```

What am I missing here? What's an app configuration?

Answer (score 8):

In order to import a JSS application using the code-first approach, or to utilize server-side rendering for either a code-first or Sitecore-first JSS application, you need to first [create an app configuration](https://jss.sitecore.net/#/sitecore-net-dev?id=app-configuration) using a Sitecore [configuration patch](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/81/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/using_patch_files_to_customize_the_sitecore_configuration). There is an example minimal app configuration patch installed with JSS at

`\App_Config\Sitecore\JavaScriptServices\Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ExampleApp.config.example`

The App Configuration documentation linked above provides information on all the available attributes for your app.

For the sample apps, this is actually even easier, as a configuration patch is provided for you. Assuming you provided the correct web root path during `npm run setup` (check `scjssconfig.json`), simply execute

`npm run config:deploy`

... and the config patch will be copied to your Sitecore instance.

Answer (score 0):

I saw the same error while doing import.

Just make sure config file name '/sitecore/config/*.config' matches to your site's 'name' property in config.

For ex.

```
/sitecore/config -> **sitecore-jss**.config
```

And inside config:

```
<site patch:before="site[@name='website']"
            inherits="website"
            **name="sitecore-jss"**
            hostName="sc93sc-jss.dev.local"
            rootPath="/sitecore/content/sitecore-jss"
            startItem="/home"
            database="master" />
```

Hope this will solve your issue.