# Configuration error in JSS Sitecore Quick start for development

Tags: configuration, javascript, jss

Configuration error while browsing Sitecore basic jss app after performing deployment steps mentioned in below link:

https://jss.sitecore.net/#/setup/app-deployment?id=app-deployment

[image: sitecore.javascriptservices application was not found]

[image]

Comment: Have you investigated the 3 pointers the error message is giving you? Is that JSSBasicApp item under the content tree an App Item, or just a folder?

Comment: In addition to the template of the App item, can you provide the [JSS] import log entries from your Sitecore log?

Comment: Retracted my close vote on this, too quick on that one. This issue is after import, existing question is during import.

Comment: Besides the "JSSBasicApp" item has a different icon (from Folder template), the Home item is missing child items. Sounds like the import process may have failed in-flight. Logs should shed some light. I would also try to delete the JSSBasicApp item and re-run `npm run package`

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Could not find JSS app configuration" error during JSS import](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8425/could-not-find-jss-app-configuration-error-during-jss-import)

Comment: Thank you all, resolved by deleting JSSBasicApp item and re-runned "npm run package" step.

Comment: @maz it's not a dupe, error is encountered after import in this case