# Sitecore Jss config deployment error

Tags: jss

Can somebody help me to resolve this error which I am getting when deploying the same ReactBasicApp using sitecore jss

> [InstallationException]: Could not find JSS app configuration for
>   'my-first-jss-app'. Ensure you have included or previously
>   installed a configuration patch for the app.    at
>   Sitecore.Update.Installer.Items.CustomActionInstaller.Process(IProcessingContext
>   entry, IProcessingContext context)    at
>   Sitecore.Update.Installer.DiffInstaller.ExecutePostInstallationInstructions(String
>   packagePath, String historyPath, InstallMode mode, MetadataView view,
>   ILog installationProcessLogger, List`1& entries)    at
>   Sitecore.Ship.Infrastructure.Update.UpdatePackageRunner.Execute(String
>   packagePath, Boolean disableIndexing)    at
>   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.Package.InstallUploadPackageCommand.HandleRequest(HttpContextBase
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.Package.InstallPackageCommand.HandleRequest(HttpContextBase
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.AboutCommand.HandleRequest(HttpContextBase
>   context)    at
>   Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.BaseHttpHandler.ProcessRequest(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Thanks & Regards

Jag

Comment: Related question: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8425/could-not-find-jss-app-configuration-error-during-jss-import?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

Did you run jss deploy config?
You can manually copy the config that brings JSS app registration to your Sitecore instance.
https://jss.sitecore.net/#/setup/sitecore-config?id=step-3-config-deployment

Answer (score 1):

after running `npm run deploy-conifg` set your connection config for sitecore instance while making sure you have put the correct configs.

You can follow this article for details.

http://www.flux-digital.com/blog/getting-started-sitecore-jss/

Also you can take help for `Sitecore.Ship.AspNet.Package.InstallUploadPackageCommand.GetRequest(System.Web.HttpRequestBase)`

https://www.csharpcodi.com/vs2/2801/Sitecore.Ship/src/Sitecore.Ship.AspNet/Package/InstallUploadPackageCommand.cs/

Comment: Just a note that my blog link above is for Tech Preview 1 so for Tech Preview 2 you should use: 'jss deploy config' as mentioned by Alex.